# Table size should not resize after first time its initial load

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have created a table using ReactJS, HTML and CSS, it creates dynamic columns and rows based on the JSON data. I have not defined any specific width to each column. The width of each column will be based on the content of the JSON, takes maximum content either header or row cell with **max-width:50ch** after max-width content will get the wrap to the next line, in case if header or row cell content is less than the 50ch, takes the **width: max-content**. I have search functionality when I search for fewer content records, my table gets resize to smaller based on the lesser content records. **But it should not resize once after initial loads**. How we can achieve this. Great appreciate.

Find the below screenshot on the initial load of the table.
[image]

Find the below screenshot, when I search the abc application its filtered the records, table size resized.

[image]

Comment: Please provide minimal example to clarify the issue. also try setting the width of the table to 100%

Comment: @AnzorAsadov Above information enough, I think so. Let me know, Is it possible to stop the table resize, if yes, How can we achieve in the above scenario. Thank you.

Comment: You could also provide a CodePen example where you show the issue. This might result in some responses.